# R interpolating data across a single observation

Tags: r

New R user changing over after 20 years using SAS and 10 years of fighting excel when I went independent. Need a more efficient way to interpolate across single records on a large database (five 260,000 observation datasets). I have the hourly current profile reduced to 4 parameters, VS (surface current) DZ (depth of zero speed), DH (mid depth point), Vh (mid depth speed).  A sample and key to how the parameters are used is given below.  For single observations, I can interpolate across the record as follows

```
    DH = 60; Vh=100;VS=200;DZ=100        
    x = (c(0,DH, DZ))
    y = (c(VS,VH,0))
    Vh50 = approx(x=x,y=y,xout=50,method="linear",rule=1:1,ties="max")$y
```

approx nicely sets out of range values to NA. Unfortunately, this fails when fed a column of a data frame.   The only way that I could solve this was to process the file row by row as shown below.  I'm now in my second hour of processing.

```
   Input$DHtemp = ifelse(Input$DH>Input$DZ,Input$DZ,Input$DH)   
   n=max(Input$rank);n
   Input$x=cbind(Input$D0,Input$DHtemp,Input$DZ)
   Input$y=cbind(Input$VS,Input$VH,Input$VZ)
   head(Input)
   for (i in seq(from=1, to=n, by=1)) { 
      Input[i,"V50"] = approx(x=c(Input[i,"D0"],Input[i,"DHtemp"],Input[i,"DZ"]),
           y=c(Input[i,"VS"],Input[i,"VH"],Input[i,"VZ"]),
           xout=Input[i,"V_1"],method="linear",rule=1:1,ties="max")$y
          }

    DATA AND KEY TO DATA 

    HRS VS  DZ  DH  VH      KEY to data
    1   209 109 106 11      Depth   Speed
    2   211 111 109 8       0        VS
    3   213 112 110 9       DH       VH
    4   213 113 109 16      DZ       0
    5   215 115 111 16          
    6   216 118 114 13
```

Comment: Nothing like posting a question to organize your thoughts.  The simple solution is to not force a round peg into a square but rather to simply interpolate 

        V_1 = 50
        V50 =   ifelse(V_1<=DH,VS+(V_1)*(VS-VH)/(0-DH),
                ifelse(V_1>DZ,NA,VH-(DH-V_1)*(VH-0)/(DH-DZ)))
  
Job ran in a few seconds.  My force fit of the approx function was still running after 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the same function to many rows of a data frame, you will want to use the `plyr` package. You haven't specified how the output should look, so I will take a guess. `daply` will apply the function you created for one row to each of the rows.

```
library(plyr)

Input <- data.frame(HRS = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                    VS = c(209, 211, 213, 213),  
                    DZ = c(109, 111, 112, 113),  
                    DH = c(106, 109, 110,109),  
                    VH = c(11, 8, 9, 16))

approx_frame <- function(df) {
  x <- c(0, df$DH, df$DZ)
  y <- c(df$VS, df$VH, 0)
  result <- approx(x=x, y=y, xout=50, method="linear", rule=1:1, ties="max")
  return(result$y)
}

daply(Input, "HRS", approx_frame)
```

If this is still too slow for you, you will want to look at the `data.table` package.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `approx` so I'm just not familiar with the syntax, but instead of looping over rows you can and should use either `apply` (base R) or `daply` (package `plyr`).

The base R solution:

```
Input[,"V50"] <- apply(Input,1,function(row){
    approx(x=row["D0"],row["DHtemp"],row["DZ"]),
       y=c(row["VS"],row["VH"],row["VZ"]),
       xout=row["V_1"],method="linear",rule=1:1,ties="max")$y
    })
```

The first argument is a data frame or matrix. The second argument is `1` meaning "dimension 1" or "margin 1," i.e. rows. The third argument is a function to apply to each row.

A possible `plyr` solution:

```
Input[,"V50"] <- daply(Input,.(1:n),function(row){
    approx(x=row["D0"],row["DHtemp"],row["DZ"]),
       y=c(row["VS"],row["VH"],row["VZ"]),
       xout=row["V_1"],method="linear",rule=1:1,ties="max")$y
    })
```

The only difference in this case is that instead of specifying a "margin," you specify a vector that indicates which group a row belongs to, using a function `.` that's part of `plyr`. Since each row is its own group in this case, the grouping vector is just the row indices.

There is also a function `aaply` that I has identical syntax to `apply`, but it doesn't return what you think it would by analogy. To use the margin syntax instead of group syntax you would need to use `laply` instead, and then call `as.vector` on the output. I'd like to hear from some other users about what `aaply` is doing here.

Note that `plyr` tends to be faster than base R, but can sometimes be more complicated to use. As the other answer mentioned, there's also the related `data.table` package and *also* the `dplyr` package which (I think) is a version of `plyr` that's optimized in some way.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing like posting a question to organize your thoughts. The simple solution is to not force a round peg into a square but rather to simply interpolate.  simple example follows.  Job ran in a few seconds. My force fit of the approx function was still running after 3 hours.

Inelegantly written, the solution was as follows.

```
#Interpolate velocity profile to standard depths
#  x is depth
#  y is velocity
#  xi = desired depths
# DH = thickness of upper layer
# DH = thickness of lower layer
# VS = surface speed
# VH = speed at depth H
InputOWIhr$D0 = 0
InputOWIhr$VZ =0
InputOWIhr$V_1=25
InputOWIhr$V_2=50
InputOWIhr$V_3=200
InputOWIhr$V_4=400

attach(InputOWIhr)
### reset this so that V = 0 if target is deeper than DZ
InputOWIhr$V25 =    ifelse(InputOWIhr$V_1<=InputOWIhr$DH,VS+(V_1)*(VS-
  VH)/(0-DH),ifelse(V_1>DZ,0,VH-(DH-V_1)*(VH-0)/(DH-DZ)))
InputOWIhr$V50 =    ifelse(InputOWIhr$V_2<=InputOWIhr$DH,VS+(V_2)*(VS-
    VH)/(0-DH),ifelse(V_2>DZ,0,VH-(DH-V_2)*(VH-0)/(DH-DZ)))
InputOWIhr$V200 =   ifelse(InputOWIhr$V_3<=InputOWIhr$DH,VS+(V_3)*(VS-
    VH)/(0-DH),ifelse(V_3>DZ,0,VH-(DH-V_3)*(VH-0)/(DH-DZ)))
InputOWIhr$V400 =   ifelse(InputOWIhr$V_4<=InputOWIhr$DH,VS+(V_4)*(VS-
    VH)/(0-DH),ifelse(V_4>DZ,0,VH-(DH-V_4)*(VH-0)/(DH-DZ)))
detach(InputOWIhr)
```

This could be simplified if I reduce it to a function call such as the following which I now use to interpolate currents at a given depth from the mean profile.

```
#Interpolate velocity profile from mean at standard depths
#  x is depth
#  y is velocity
#  xi = desired depths

VbarGOM <- function(Zi) { 
    Z=c(0,50,100,200,400,800,1200,1325)
    Vbar=c(35.26640258,28.74863283,22.23086307,19.22705602,13.20431536,6.676782584,4.677900862,5.6489939)
    result = approx(x=Z,y=Vbar,xout=Zi,method="linear",rule=1:1,ties="max")$y
    return(result)
    }

VbarGOM(10)
```

Comment: I think you can remove this answer too.